# Yii2 fixtures data loading from two different paths

Tags: unit-testing, yii2, codeception, fixtures

Trying to load a fixture that depends on another one:

```
namespace app\tests\fixtures;

use yii\test\ActiveFixture;

class UserFixture extends ActiveFixture {
    public $modelClass = 'app\models\User';

    public $depends = [
        'app\tests\fixtures\ProfileFixture',
    ];
}
```

This fails:

> `Fixture data file does not exist:`
>   `/var/www/vhosts/somedomain.com/httpdocs/yii2/tests/fixtures/data/profile.php`

The fixture data is in `../yii2/tests/_data` so it's looking for the data file in the wrong spot. How do I change this path?

Answer (score 1):

In fixture class `ProfileFixture` add path to data file

```
class ProfileFixture extends ActiveFixture {
   public $modelClass = 'app\models\Prodile';

   public $dataFile = '@yii2/tests/_data/profile.php';
}
```

But I think it's better to move your data file to this namespace `app\tests\fixtures\data\profile.php`